# How to make a multiplication table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Still a beginner in using jquery, and its about making a calculator, I know this is a big problem because it still has an error in it and there's a lot of code to be done to make it work, so what I need is adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing two numbers, and upon pressing the operator the first number that was pressed wouldn't be gone rather it will be gone and be change after pressing for the second number. It would also be a big thanks if y'all could help me my problem. Thanks a lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var number = "";
  $(".numeric").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).val();
    number = number + "" + num;
    $("#container").val(number);
  });

  $(".clear").click(function() {
    $("#container").val("");
    number = "";
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sample Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="container" placeholder="" readOnly="readOnly" />
  <br /><br />
  <table border="1" cellpadding="3">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="numeric" value="7" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="numeric" value="8" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="numeric" value="9" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="operation" value="+" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="numeric" value="4" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="numeric" value="5" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="numeric" value="6" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="operation" value="-" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="numeric" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="numeric" value="2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="numeric" value="3" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="operation" value="*" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="numeric" value="0" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="operation" value="=" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="operation" value="/" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" class="clear" value="Clear" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: @Chamcham, stackoverflow is not a community to create a solution. If you have any problem ask here. You are asking here a readymade solution.

Comment: Sorry, still having a hard time understanding jquery, and it so hard to find exact references for my code.